# Count unique values by group (data.table) doesn't work

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm trying to count the unique values from a variable (`ruc_pk_informante`) by two groups (`year` and `pn_soc_informante`) with `data.table` but I get different values from `dplyr` (I used `tidytable`).

## data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(tidytable)

> tt[, .(count = uniqueN(ruc_pk_informante)), by = .(sort(year),pn_soc_informante)]
# A tidytable: 4 x 3
   sort pn_soc_informante count
  <int> <chr>             <int>
1  2012 PERSONA NATURAL       1
2  2013 PERSONA NATURAL      10 --------->????
3  2014 PERSONA NATURAL       8
4  2015 PERSONA NATURAL       1
```

## dplyr and manually

```
> tt %>% arrange.(year) %>% summarise.(n_distinct.(ruc_pk_informante), .by = c(year, pn_soc_informante))
# A tidytable: 4 x 3
   year pn_soc_informante    V1
  <int> <chr>             <int>
1  2012 PERSONA NATURAL       1
2  2013 PERSONA NATURAL      17 --------> OK!
3  2014 PERSONA NATURAL      12
4  2015 PERSONA NATURAL      13
> t1 = tt %>% filter.(year == 2013)
> length(unique(t1$ruc_pk_informante)) # OK!
[1] 17
```

## Data

```
# data ---------------------------------------------------------------------


tt = structure(list(ruc_pk_informante = c("R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", 
                                     "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", 
                                     "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", 
                                     "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", 
                                     "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", 
                                     "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", 
                                     "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "R5", "R5", "R7", "R7", "R7", "R7", 
                                     "C9", "C9", "R12", "R12", "R12", "R14", "R16", "R16", "R16", 
                                     "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", 
                                     "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", "R16", 
                                     "C21", "R23", "R23", "R23", "R23", "R23", "R23", "R23", "R23", 
                                     "R23", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", 
                                     "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", 
                                     "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R27", "R30", "R30", "R30", 
                                     "R30", "R33", "R33", "R33", "R33", "R33", "R33", "R34", "R34", 
                                     "R34", "R34", "R37", "R41", "R41", "R41", "R41", "R41", "R41", 
                                     "R41", "R44", "R44", "R44", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", 
                                     "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45", "R45"
), year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
            2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
            2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
            2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 
            2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
            2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2013L, 2015L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
            2013L, 2015L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
            2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 
            2015L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
            2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
            2015L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2014L, 2015L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 
            2015L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
            2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 
            2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
            2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
            2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
            2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L
), pn_soc_informante = c("PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", 
                         "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL", "PERSONA NATURAL"
)), row.names = c(NA, -250L), class = c("tidytable", "data.table", 
                                        "data.frame"), index = structure(integer(0), "`__year`" = c(67L, 
                                                                                                                                                       1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
                                                                                                                                                       15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 65L, 68L, 71L, 73L, 76L, 
                                                                                                                                                       77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 108L, 109L, 
                                                                                                                                                       110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 131L, 135L, 136L, 141L, 
                                                                                                                                                       142L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 153L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
                                                                                                                                                       162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 
                                                                                                                                                       173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 
                                                                                                                                                       184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 
                                                                                                                                                       195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 
                                                                                                                                                       206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
                                                                                                                                                       26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
                                                                                                                                                       39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 69L, 
                                                                                                                                                       74L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
                                                                                                                                                       117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 132L, 137L, 138L, 143L, 148L, 149L, 
                                                                                                                                                       154L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 
                                                                                                                                                       224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 
                                                                                                                                                       235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 
                                                                                                                                                       246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
                                                                                                                                                       58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 66L, 70L, 72L, 75L, 91L, 92L, 
                                                                                                                                                       93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 
                                                                                                                                                       125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 133L, 134L, 139L, 140L, 144L, 
                                                                                                                                                       150L, 151L, 152L, 155L)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sort` on the `by` is breaking the order for the rows - i.e. it is rearranging the `year` separately and this would result in erroneous values from other columns matching with the sorted column of 'year'.  It should be either on the `i`

```
tt[order(year), .(count = uniqueN(ruc_pk_informante)), 
     by = .(year, pn_soc_informante)]
# A tidytable: 4 × 3
   year pn_soc_informante count
  <int> <chr>             <int>
1  2012 PERSONA NATURAL       1
2  2013 PERSONA NATURAL      17
3  2014 PERSONA NATURAL      12
4  2015 PERSONA NATURAL      13
```

---

or do the order later

```
tt[, .(count = uniqueN(ruc_pk_informante)), 
   by = .(year, pn_soc_informante)][order(year)]
# A tidytable: 4 × 3
   year pn_soc_informante count
  <int> <chr>             <int>
1  2012 PERSONA NATURAL       1
2  2013 PERSONA NATURAL      17
3  2014 PERSONA NATURAL      12
4  2015 PERSONA NATURAL      13
```

---

Check the output from the sorted and unsorted

```
> tt[, .SD, by = .(year = year,pn_soc_informante)][year == 2013]$ruc_pk_informante
  [1] "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3" 
 [23] "R5"  "R7"  "C9"  "R12" "R14" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "C21" "R23" "R23" "R23" "R27" "R27" "R27" "R27" "R27" "R27" "R27"
 [45] "R27" "R27" "R30" "R33" "R33" "R34" "R34" "R37" "R41" "R41" "R44" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45"
 [67] "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45"
 [89] "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45" "R45"
[111] "R45" "R45" "R45"
> tt[, .SD, by = .(year = sort(year),pn_soc_informante)][year == 2013]$ruc_pk_informante
  [1] "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3" 
 [23] "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3" 
 [45] "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R3"  "R5"  "R5"  "R7" 
 [67] "R7"  "R7"  "R7"  "C9"  "C9"  "R12" "R12" "R12" "R14" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16"
 [89] "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "R16" "C21" "R23" "R23" "R23" "R23" "R23" "R23" "R23" "R23" "R23" "R27" "R27" "R27" "R27"
[111] "R27" "R27" "R27"
```

Comment: why doesn't work `sort` on your code?

Comment: @cdcarrion `sort` does work, but you are sorting a single column and breaking the sorting on other columns.  That is the reason I used order so that all the columns are ordered by the year column